# fetch => response.json() request being rejected

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a website I'm trying to pull some data from. I'm using the window debugger to copy the fetch

```
fetch("website", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"})
.then(response => {console.log(response)})
```

This works, and I'm able to inspect the response in the debugger. I want to access the body of data:

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: website
__proto__: Response
```

I read that I need to turn it into a json object like this:

```
fetch("website", {"credentials":"include","headers":{"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"},"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade","body":null,"method":"GET","mode":"cors"})
    .then(response => {console.log(response.json())})
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseValue]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
```

I don't understand too much about fetch and trying to piece together what fetch is doing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the `body` data?

Comment: Well you're accepting HTML and want the `Response`'s JSON

Comment: can you elaborate or write a snippet of code? I don't quite understand what that means

Comment: You’re specifying `headers` with `accept: 'text/html,[…]'` where […] is a bunch of stuff that doesn’t include `application/json`. This may or may not matter.

Comment: How do I access the response data that is `text/html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your request headers you specify that you will accept a `text/html` response.

Try specifying the correct MIME type `application/json` instead - and the API should return proper json data as a response.

If you intend to fetch it as text, you can access the text data with `response.text()` instead of `response.json()`

(see fetch documentation on [Response body methods](https://github.github.io/fetch#response-body))

Comment: ahh ok. I can't change the request/header, it is not my API. How do I access the text/html?

Comment: You can use `.text()` instead of `.json()`